# Find position of Paired Numbers in Array

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, sorting

let input arr=[9,**4,4**,8,90,4,9,**4,4**,***4,4***,**4,4**,***4,4***,4,7,9,2,**4,4**,***4,4***,4,8,**4,4**,***4,4***];

let output arr=[1,7,9,11,13,15,19,21,25,27];

Above is an input array of numbers which contain mostly 4, if there is a pair of 4 which means (Input elements has 2 of the number 4 consecutively), its array position will be displayed in the output array. I have tried my code below but I am still unsure on how to solve this :).  May I know how to solve this?

```js
console.clear();
let arr=[8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7,9,2,4,4,4,4,4,8,4,4,4,4];

console.log("his")
for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
if (arr[i]!==arr[i+1] &&arr[i]!==4 ){
console.log(i)
}
if (arr[i]!==arr[i+1] &&arr[i+1]!==4 ){
console.log(i+1)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look to the next item and if the last index is not in the result array, the add the actual index to the result.

```js
const
    input = [9, 4, 4, 8, 90, 4, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4],
    result = input.reduce((r, v, i, a) => {
        if (v === a[i + 1] && r[r.length - 1] !== i - 1) r.push(i);
        return r;
    }, []);

console.log(...result);
```

An approach for *n* elements with a closure over a counting variable `c`.

```js
const
    getIndices = (array, n) => input.reduce((c => (r, v, i, a) => {
        if (!c) {
            if (v === a[i + 1]) c = 1;
            return r;
        }

        c = v === a[i - 1] ? c + 1 : 0;
        
        if (c === n) {
            r.push(i - n + 1);
            c = 0;
        }
        return r;
    })(0), []),
    input = [9, 4, 4, 8, 90, 4, 9, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 7, 9, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4];

console.log(...getIndices(input, 2));
console.log(...getIndices(input, 3));
console.log(...getIndices(input, 4));
console.log(...getIndices(input, 5));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, miss. What if the question is changed to 3 consecutive of Number 4 instead of 2 consecutive Number 4 (Pair) in my input array :) ? Like if I create an input function for number N which stands for (N consecutive Number 4, N=2, means 2 of Number 4 (pair) and 3 means 3 of Number 4

Comment: that is indeed a bit tricky, because before adding the index, it should take a look ahead for the following values and check the equalness.

Comment: Yes, haha. Well, I need this logic to fix a bug in my app haha:)

Comment: Hi, thanks for taking the time of solving it, seriously, this is too tricky for me as beginner :)

Answer (score 2):

This is a possible solution:

```
console.clear();
let arr=[8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,7,9,2,4,4,4,4,4,8,4,4,4,4];
let pair = false;

for (let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  if (pair == false) {
      if (arr[i]==arr[i+1]){
        console.log(i)
        pair = true; // show that we have found a pair
      }              // thus we skip a 'for' loop
  }
  else {
    pair = false; // reset the pair variable
  }
}
```

output: [1, 3, 5, 7, 13, 15, 19, 21]

Do you want this pair:
let arr=[8,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,**4,4**,7,9,2,4,4,4,4,4,8,4,4,4,4];

to be counted, as well?

Comment: Yes, of course, Pair :)

Comment: My mistake in question sorry :)

Comment: Do you want three consecutive numbers to be counted as two pairs, or just one pair? In the first case, if you have an array, like your sample array, pairs may be counted two times, instead of one. The second case I have already solved. For example ``` [2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5] ``` will have 5 pairs instead of 3!

Comment: Hi Marco, thanks for reply, if [2,4,4,4,4,4,4,5], means that output should be [1,4], the first position of the 3 consecutive Number 4 :)

Comment: So its like, What if the question is changed to 3 consecutive of Number 4 instead of 2 consecutive Number 4 (Pair) in my input array :) ? Like if I create an input function for number N which stands for (N consecutive Number 4, N=2, means 2 of Number 4 (pair) and 3 means 3 of Number 4